# "file not found" error when reinstalling GRUB

Tags: grub

I'm trying to reinstall GRUP after installing Windows.

```
sudo grub

grub>find /boot/grub/stage1
```

After this, I'm getting the error "file not found".

Can anyone help me?

Comment: maybe this helps: http://forums.scotsnewsletter.com/lofiversion/index.php/t27563.html

Comment: Were you able to boot Linux? Is that code the grub console or a linux console?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reboot with a Linux CD (for example Debian installation CD), than enter in recovery mode and mount your Linux root partition (and `/boot` if it is in a separate partition). After that launch `grub-install` as root in recovery shell (the shell running in the system you have on your HD).